# two way binding between input box and expression

Tags: angularjs

what would be the way to handle being able to change the expression from the text field and the other way around as well. For example:

```
myApp.controller('MainContrller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.inputs = {
     'input1': 'text'
   }
}]);
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.input1">
  <p>This will output {{ inputs.input1 }}</p>
</div>
```

This works well when the binding goes from the input to the expression, but I am also using contenteditable and would like for the expression in there to replace what is in the input box as well. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the content editable example of ngModelController documentation, under section "Custom Control Example"

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Basically it creates  directive to bind the `ng-model` field to changes in content editable. You can then use the same ng-model expression to bind the contenteditable and input so changes are in sync.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference and help